# Automaticly fill column

Tags: sql

I have two columns in a table (ex. column1, column2), one INT and the other VARCHAR types. I need to combine both in another column (ex. column3) and I don't want to do it manually. Is there a way to fill this third column with a combine of the other two column with a specific format using some SQLl query?

Example:

```
column1 column2 column3
8       munson  munson, 8
23      gatine  gatine, 23
63      carbon  carbon, 63
```

Thanks,

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it on the fly (Just query the 3 new columns)
You can do:

```
Select column1,colum2, CONCAT_WS(column2,', ',CAST(column1 as TEXT)) as column3 from table;
```

If you are trying to modify the original table to add a new column you can do something like:

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    column3 = CONCAT_WS(column2,', ',CAST(column1 as TEXT))
```

The previous snippet should work for postgresql. Other engines will have different syntax for updating a column.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to change the order of elements in the function CONCAT_WS to obtain the format I wanted.

````
CONCAT_WS(', ', column2,CAST(column1 as TEXT))
````